# Detect plain text file encoding

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding

I am working with text files from which I load the text content to send through API (as the body of a PUT request). Typically, I use readLines()

```
my_text_content <- readLines(con = "path\to\file.txt")
```

The distant app has problem to deal with non UTF-8 text encoding. And it appears that some users in Windows, using Notepad++ to write their scripts, dont default to UTF-8 but most often ANSI.

I found on other questions how to convert encoding using iconv(), but I would first like to detect file encoding to raise a warning to the user (and eventually convert encoding then).

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(readr)

guess_encoding("text.txt")

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  encoding confidence
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 ASCII             1
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not think to readr::guess_encoding(), which I use on text file for tabular data. 
It seems to be working !

Comment: @pwaeckerle You can also look at ```stri_enc_detect``` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringi/versions/1.7.5/topics/stri_enc_detect ```guess_encoding``` based on it. But its output should be parsed, which demands extra movements.

Comment: Yes, I discovered `stri_enc_detect` reading the documentation of `guess_encoding`. It has more options so I might use it for analysis purposes. On my exact case, the default options of `guess_encoding` are fine and, as you say, the data.frame I retrieve is easier to handle.